# Table value type in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any way to check all table value types already being declared in SQL Server 2008 database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want this [sys.table_types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510623%28v=sql.105%29.aspx),

```
select * from  sys.table_types
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the structures of types having in this table ?

Comment: Each table type has a `type_table_object_id` that is a foreign key into the `sys.objects`, so you can use join between them. sys.object displays the property for particular object